# lua deepcopy select index / values to new table and then print new table

Tags: lua

new to lua and I need some help figuring out the deepcopy process from the lua users wiki. Basically, I have an in ipairs table with multiple attributes per index chunk, and I want to copy the entire index chunk where the attributes meet certain if conditions, run in a for loop. Finally, I want to print the new table contents.

The table is very long so I'll just include a short excerpt.

```
local tblStudents = {
    {
        ['Name'] = 'Jeff',
        ['Year'] = 'Twelve-A',
        ['Class'] = 'Ms Edwards',
        ['Attended'] = true
    },
    {
        ['Name'] = 'Tom',
        ['Year'] = 'Twelve-B',
        ['Class'] = 'Ms Edwards',
        ['Attended'] = true
    },
    {
        ['Name'] = 'Billy',
        ['Year'] = 'Twelve-A',
        ['Class'] = 'Ms Edwards',
        ['Attended'] = false
    },
    {
        ['Name'] = 'Jack',
        ['Year'] = 'Twelve-B',
        ['Class'] = 'Ms Edwards',
        ['Attended'] = false
    },
    {
        ['Name'] = 'Sam',
        ['Year'] = 'Twelve-A',
        ['Class'] = 'Mr Green',
        ['Attended'] = true
    },
    {
        ['Name'] = 'Diego',
        ['Year'] = 'Twelve-A',
        ['Class'] = 'Mr Green',
        ['Attended'] = false
    },
    {
        ['Name'] = 'Peta',
        ['Year'] = 'Twelve-A',
        ['Class'] = 'Mr Green',
        ['Attended'] = false
    },
    {
        ['Name'] = 'Will',
        ['Year'] = 'Twelve-A',
        ['Class'] = 'Ms Edwards',
        ['Attended'] = true
    },
    {
        ['Name'] = 'Sara',
        ['Year'] = 'Twelve-B',
        ['Class'] = 'Ms Edwards',
        ['Attended'] = true
    },
    {
        ['Name'] = 'Lisa',
        ['Year'] = 'Twelve-A',
        ['Class'] = 'Ms Edwards',
        ['Attended'] = true
    }
}
```

What I want to do is deepcopy all of the students from Twelve-A who didn't attend to a new table, tblTruant I imagine the statement to do so would use the conditional:

```
for i,v in ipairs (tblStudents) do
    if v.Year == 'Twelve-A' and v.Attended == false then
        --deepcopy to new table.
```

The demo code I've been given for deepcopy is this:

```
local function deepCopy(original)
    local copy = {}
    for k, v in pairs(original) do
        if type(v) == "table" then
            v = deepCopy(v)
        end
        copy[k] = v
    end
    return copy
end
```

I'm not sure how to apply that using the conditional outlined above.

For printing the results of the new table, I've been told as I can't print a table as a string, to use this recursive function:

```
function dump(o)
   if type(o) == 'table' then
      local s = '{ '
      for k,v in pairs(o) do
         if type(k) ~= 'number' then k = '"'..k..'"' end
         s = s .. '['..k..'] = ' .. dump(v) .. ','
      end
      return s .. '} '
   else
      return tostring(o)
   end
end
```

My presumption would be that this would allow me to use print(dump(tblTruant) to get the desired result.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to do much more than you already have. Just create the new table and insert the interesting items into it:

```
tblTruant = {} -- create a new empty table
for i,v in ipairs (tblStudents) do
    if v.Year == 'Twelve-A' and v.Attended == false then
        table.insert(tblTruant, deepCopy(v)) -- deepcopy to new table

print(dump(tblTruant)) -- print the new table contents
```

Any possible improvements to `dump` or `deepCopy` are another matter entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Your `deepcopy` function needs some improvement:

- it doesn't handle the case when `original` is not a table,
- since `key` can be a table (though not in your example), it needs to be deeply copied,
- deep copy assumes copying reference to the metatable, albeit you are not using one,
- there is another issue with `deepCopy` and `dump`. Although it is irrelevant with the table in the examples, generic tables can be recursive, that is, contain references to themselves. This has to be dealt with. A possible way is to keep a "set" of tables that are already being processed by the functions. This set can be stored as a table local to the same scope as the function it serves, yet to make it "static", i.e., available from the function, both can be wrappen in a second-order function.

An improved version:

```lua
local concat = table.concat
local function handleRecursiveTables (func, stub)
    local calls = {}
    return function (arg)
        if type (arg) == 'table' and calls [arg] then
            return stub (arg)
        end
        calls [arg] = true
        return func (arg)
    end
end

local function deepCopy (original)
    local copy
    if type (original) ~= 'table' then
        copy = original
    else
        copy = {}
        for key, value in pairs (original) do
            copy [deepCopy (key)] = deepCopy (value)
        end
    end
    if type (original) == 'table' or type (original) == 'userdata' then
        setmetatable (copy, getmetatable (original))
    end
    return copy
end
deepCopy = handleRecursiveTables (deepCopy, function (original)
    return original
end)
```

Call it like this:

```lua
local truants = {}
for i,v in ipairs (tblStudents) do
    if v.Year == 'Twelve-A' and v.Attended == false then
        --deepcopy to new table.
        truants [#truants + 1] = deepCopy (v)
    end
end
```

Similar improvements for `dump` making it more generic:

```lua
local function dump (o)
    if type (o) == 'string' then
        return '"' .. o .. '"'
    elseif type (o) == 'table' then
        local items = {}
        for key, value in pairs (o) do
            items [#items + 1] = '[' .. dump (key) .. '] = ' .. dump (value)
        end
        return '[' .. concat (items, ', ') .. ']'
    else
        return tostring (o)
    end
end
dump = handleRecursiveTables (dump, function (o)
    return '(recursive table reference)'
end)
```

**UPD** A full working example:

```lua
-- Utility function to handle recursive tables. Not really necesary, bit demonstrates some principles.
-- A similar technique is used for caching expensive function calls.
local concat = table.concat -- localise table value to speed it up.
-- func is a function that takes one argument of the type table and needs to be enabled to handle recursive tables.
-- stub is the function that handles the table if the table has already been processed to stop infinite recursion.
local function handleRecursiveTables (func, stub)
    local calls = {} -- a set of already processed tables.
    return function (arg)
        if type (arg) == 'table' then
            if calls [arg] then
                return stub (arg)   -- stop recursion.
            end
            calls [arg] = true -- remember that arg has been processed.
        end
        return func (arg)   -- actually call the function.
    end
end

-- Naïve implementation of deep copy.
local function deepCopy (original)
    local copy
    if type (original) ~= 'table' then
        copy = original -- not a table, so simply return the scalar value.
    else
        copy = {}
        for key, value in pairs (original) do
            -- We need to deep copy both the key and the value, as any can be a table.
            copy [deepCopy (key)] = deepCopy (value)
        end
    end
    -- Copy the reference to the metatable, if any.
    if type (original) == 'table' or type (original) == 'userdata' then
        setmetatable (copy, getmetatable (original))
    end
    return copy
end
-- Make the function aware of recursive tables.
-- Not that recursive calls of deepCopy will also be affected.
deepCopy = handleRecursiveTables (deepCopy, function (original)
    return original
end)

-- Naïve implementation of dump.
local function dump (o)
    if type (o) == 'string' then
        return '"' .. o .. '"'  -- quote the string, wherever it appears.
    elseif type (o) == 'table' then
        local items = {}    -- '[key] = value' chunks.
        for key, value in pairs (o) do
            -- Use dumped key and value.
            items [#items + 1] = '[' .. dump (key) .. '] = ' .. dump (value)
        end
        -- table.concat once is faster than applying .. again and again.
        -- Also, there will be no trailing comma.
        return '[' .. concat (items, ', ') .. ']'
    else
        return tostring (o) -- numbers, functions, userdata.
    end
end
-- Make the function aware of recursive tables.
-- Not that recursive calls of dump will also be affected.
dump = handleRecursiveTables (dump, function (o)
    return '(recursive table reference)'
end)

-- This function filters out truants from the given year and returns a table of their deep copies.
local function getTruants (students, year)
    local truants = {}
    for _, student in ipairs (students) do -- we don't need the key, so use _ as the variable name.
        if student.Year == year and student.Attended == false then
        -- you can use 'not student.Attended' instead of 'student.Attended == false'
        -- but in this case, if Attended has not been explicitly set, it will be falsy.
            --deepcopy to new table.
            truants [#truants + 1] = deepCopy (student)
        end
    end
    return truants
end

-- Test dataset:
local tblStudents = {
    {
        -- Note that Name = 'Jeff' is the same as ['Name'] = 'Jeff'.
        -- 'Name' has to consist of underscores, letters (at least one of either) and numbers.
        Name = 'Jeff',
        Year = 'Twelve-A',
        Class = 'Ms Edwards',
        Attended = true
    },
    {
        Name = 'Tom',
        Year = 'Twelve-B',
        Class = 'Ms Edwards',
        Attended = true
    },
    {
        Name = 'Billy',
        Year = 'Twelve-A',
        Class = 'Ms Edwards',
        Attended = false
    },
    {
        Name = 'Jack',
        Year = 'Twelve-B',
        Class = 'Ms Edwards',
        Attended = false
    },
    {
        Name = 'Sam',
        Year = 'Twelve-A',
        Class = 'Mr Green',
        Attended = true
    },
    {
        Name = 'Diego',
        Year = 'Twelve-A',
        Class = 'Mr Green',
        Attended = false
    },
    {
        Name = 'Peta',
        Year = 'Twelve-A',
        Class = 'Mr Green',
        Attended = false
    },
    {
        Name = 'Will',
        Year = 'Twelve-A',
        Class = 'Ms Edwards',
        Attended = true
    },
    {
        Name = 'Sara',
        Year = 'Twelve-B',
        Class = 'Ms Edwards',
        Attended = true
    },
    {
        Name = 'Lisa',
        Year = 'Twelve-A',
        Class = 'Ms Edwards',
        Attended = true
    }
}

-- The following line is an example of a self-reference in a table.
-- Without handleRecursiveTables it would cause infinite recursion.
tblStudents [1].allStudents = tblStudents

-- Print a list of truants.
print (dump (getTruants (tblStudents, 'Twelve-A')))
```

Comment: "therefore, the recursion will not work as expected, either," does not follow from "it doesn't handle the case when original is not a table;"

Comment: How "v = deepCopy(v) will change v in-place, i.e., in original."?

Comment: Tables are references, so, `original[k]` will be replaced with its deep copy. On the first issue, you're are probably right.

Comment: But it is not changing `original[k]`. It is changing the *variable* `v` from a reference into the original to the result of the recursive call. `var = foo` is *not* `var.whatever = foo`.

Comment: This is all good, but I'm completely lost when it comes to actually applying it. Sorry to be such a newb, but could someone demonstrate how to apply those to the problem please? I keep getting errors, and I don't really understand what I'm doing. In text comments would be super appreciated!

Comment: I have added a complete working example, with comments.

Comment: Thank you all for your input - super useful to increase my understanding